# Pausing a Kernel Build while signing bzImage

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, rhel7

I am trying to pause a kernel build(rhel7) just before it sign bzImage (BuildKernel) function in kernel.spec and copy a signed bzImage from other computer in current build server.

Comment: so where is the question?.

Comment: Apologies for missing "?" .Is there any way to pause rpmbuild or mock build in between? Though i able to do it by asking for dummy user input using:                                                                                                    

echo "Do you want to install <some package> [Y/n] "
if exec </dev/tty; then
    read input;
fi

Is there anything we can try?